# Laravel artisan migrate error: "zsh: illegal hardware instruction php artisan migrate"

Tags: php, laravel, macos, terminal, laravel-artisan

I'm using Laravel 7, when I launch from terminal php artisan migrate, I get this error

```
zsh: illegal hardware instruction php artisan migrate
```

All other artisan commands works fine like php artisan make:model or php artisan make:migration

System requirements:
PHP 7.4.5 (cli)
Zend Engine v3.4.0
MacBook Pro Catalina 10.15.4

Thank you

Comment: could you check if there is a possible infinite loop in your migrations?

Comment: they are brand new migrations, only with the Schema::create statement (with id and timestamps columns)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Just resolved yet.

I'm using MAMP PRO for the virtual server
The problem was in the db configuration, I added in the .env file

```
DB_SOCKET=/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock
```

The default configuration in the .env file didn't work for me, this configuration will work

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_PORT=8889
DB_DATABASE=dbname
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=root
DB_SOCKET=/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock
```